# Can't build release apk with multi flavors in Flutter?

Tags: android, flutter, android-flavors

I'm using Flutter (version 1.17.4) for developing Android and config `multi Flavors` for running multi-environment.

My source code has 3 environment: `dev` (devlopment), `uat` (QC), `prod` (Production).

`Source`: https://github.com/huubao2309/demo_multi_flavors

My `multiFlavors.gradle` file (`/android/app/multiFlavors.gradle`):

```
android {
    flavorDimensions "app"

    productFlavors {
      prod {
        dimension "app"
        applicationIdSuffix ".prod"
        versionNameSuffix "-prod"
      }
      dev {
        dimension "app"
        applicationIdSuffix ".dev"
        versionNameSuffix "-dev"
      }
      uat {
        dimension "app"
        applicationIdSuffix ".uat"
        versionNameSuffix "-uat"
      }
   }
}
```

Every time, I build app for release with terminal:

```
flutter build apk --flavor uat -t lib/main-uat.dart
```

File .apk is created but terminal throws an exception:

`Gradle build failed to produce an .apk file. It's likely that this file was generated under D:\demo_multi_flavors\build, but the tool couldn't find it.`

[image: error]

I also had this problem when running in `debug` mode, but on Android Studio (version 4.0), I added config `build flavor`, the problem is resolved:

[image: add_flavor]

How to solve the problem with release mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This bug appears to be caused by Flutter looking for an exact `.apk` name, but not being able to find it. In my case, the name of the .apk being generated was `app-release-unsigned.apk` but needed to be `app-release.apk`. This was my solution:

```
  buildTypes {
    debug {
        signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
    }
    release {
        applicationVariants.all { variant ->
            variant.outputs.all {
                outputFileName = "app-${variant.getName()}.apk"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Reference: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/44796#issuecomment-602278977